# Find the sum of the list below with a for loop

Tags: python, list, loops, syntax, syntax-error

I wanted to calculate the sum of the list below, but I forgot to write (total = 0) before the loop.
I expected to get an error but when I ran the cell I got this output:

```
55
65
70
```

Now I'm confused and don't know what that code did:

```
a = [20, 10, 5]
for element in a:
    total = total + element
    print (total)
```

Comment: Looks like `total` was `35` before entering that for loop. You probably ran correctly the same code or equivalent before

Comment: .. what happened here is that OP forgot to mention to be working with command-line python instead of an editor like pyCharm or KomodoEdit. In both cases you see script instead of single line, for example "[Out 42] 55". In an exitor you can't forget to declare "total = 0" because it throws a traceback error at you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe total was initialized before as `total = 35`

Answer (score 0):

`total` seems to have another value!

you should initiate the total variable in order for it to properly work as a sum operation:

```
a = [20, 10, 5]
total = 0
for element in a:
    total = total + element
    print (total)
```

this should do the trick, but here a easier way :

```
total = sum(a)
```

it seems like the total variable has another value and was defined in a different place...

Comment: OP is already aware of that (it is mentioned in the question...)

Comment: i hope this worth somthing .... lol, thanks anyway

Comment: Now that I realized , it had already been initialized! thanks for the answers.